# Pinpoint memory leaks on IIS

Tags: memory, iis, memory-leaks

I have noticed slow performance for our web application on IIS developed under visual studio c# and vb.net.
After working for sometime on application , we notice a degradation in system performance and we have to restart IIS to restore performance again.
I have downloaded and used many tools like (debugdiag,jetbrains) to be able detect which service(s) is causing this memory leak, sometimes high cpu usage also.
Those tools give me lots of information but unfortunately ,it's all generic showing system files or string arrays etc..
Is there anyway to be able to get the applications causing this and if possible also drill down to which function or line of code causing that.
[Jetbrains analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVWAN.jpg)
I have added an image showing snapshots comparison result.
Thank you
Nader

Comment: Are you sure you’re correctly profiling your application? Just start profiling, do some requests, take a snapshot, do more requests, take another snapshot and compare the two.

Comment: Yes i did all that and created 2 snapshots and compared, there is lots of information but my problem is , i can't use this info to know which requests or apis are causing the issue as it's showing information about system files.

Comment: I’m not sure I’m following. Do you perhaps mean instances of .NET Framework types? They could also leak from your code. I suggest you [read a tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/How_to_Find_a_Memory_Leak.html).

Comment: Yes that's what i mean, Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my post and added the snapshot comparison result.

Comment: You showed too little information. The screen shot only reveals the diff between two snapshots, but you told nothing about how long was the time between them. Object count for cache related objects and strings changed, so your code in caching and string manipulation might be improper (against best practices for instance). However, don't expect an online discussion can effective solve tough cases like this. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com or hire an experience consultant to help.